# Create multiple timestamps for adjacent column values

Tags: excel, vba

I am able to get a timestamp in column C for column B values.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Update 20140722
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer
Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("B:B"), Target)
xOffsetColumn = 1
If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each Rng In WorkRng
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm:ss"
        Else
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

I need a timestamp in column E for Column D values and similarly, a timestamp in column G for column F values.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer
Dim rng1(1 To 18) As String
rng1(1) = "D:D"
rng1(2) = "M:M"
rng1(3) = "P:P"
rng1(4) = "R:R"
rng1(5) = "U:U"
rng1(6) = "W:W"
rng1(7) = "Z:Z"
rng1(8) = "AB:AB"
rng1(9) = "AE:AE"
rng1(10) = "AG:AG"
rng1(11) = "AL:AL"
rng1(12) = "AN:AN"
rng1(13) = "AQ:AQ"
rng1(14) = "AS:AS"
rng1(15) = "AV:AV"
rng1(16) = "AX:AX"
rng1(17) = "BA:BA"
rng1(18) = "BC:BC"

For I = 1 To 18
Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range(rng1(I)), Target)
xOffsetColumn = 1
If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each rng In WorkRng
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(rng.Value) Then
            rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
            rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm:ss"
        Else
            rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
        End If
    Next


    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Shivang. But below are the columns corresponding to which i need the timestamp.                                                                                                           Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("D:D","M:M","P:P","R:R","U:U","W:W","Z:Z","AB:AB","AE:AE","AG:AG","AL:AL","AN:AN","AQ:AQ","AS:AS","AV:AV","AX:AX","BA:BA","BC:BC"), Target)

Comment: This is a Warehouse live process sheet. Wherein, i need to capture process time at each step.

Comment: I have updated the code, you may run it and check, if it works fine ?

Comment: With the above code, I got Run time error 450. The above code works only for two columns("D:D","M:M") and nothing beyond two specifications.

Comment: It worked! with the above code. Thanks a lot Shivang. I am new to macros and this was of great help.